# Tag cluster: [grammar], [grammaticality], [grammaticality-in-context], [grammatical]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retagging

In my opinion, the tags clustered around [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) and [grammaticality](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality) have gotten out of hand.  All these tags: [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar), [grammaticality](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality), [grammaticality-in-context](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality-in-context), [grammatical](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical) mean basically the same thing, no?

How should we clean up this situation?

Answer (score 5):

I'd scrap 'em all.

- Some people use *grammar* and its derivatives to designate matters of morphology and concord. This was the most common use among English professors when I was young.
- Some people use them to designate sentential well-formedness: morphology-and-syntax, as distinct from phonology on one side and discourse semantics on the other. This appears be the most common use among English professors today.
- Some people use them to designate whatever is acceptable to a more or (usually) less well informed 'authority' on 'usage'. This appears to be the most common use among native-speaker laypeople.
- Some people use them in more or less the sense of Chomsky's *Syntactic Structures*, equivalent to "acceptable to a native speaker". This appears to be the most common use among our non-native-speaker visitors.

It seems to me that these terms have no consistent meaning, certainly not a meaning which makes it useful for searching or for informing users what a question is about.

Comment: Scrap them all... to be replaced by nothing? Or a new tag taxonomy? Could you propose some specifics?

Comment: @200_success I'm not at all clear [what tags are good for](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/151/32), so I'm the wrong guy to ask. But if you do see a use for one or more tags that suggest one or more of these meanings, start with the semantics.

Answer (score 2):

Replace every tag with [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar).  No one here makes any practical distinctions between any of these tags, and as far as I can tell, it's unlikely that future users are going to start.

At a minimum, boiling these tags down to the two ELU uses is preferable to keeping the four we have now.  But if you want to keep two tags, vote for [200_success's answer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/tag-cluster-grammar-grammaticality-grammaticality-in-context-grammati/1020#1020) rather than this one; this answer is about keeping only one tag.

Answer (score 0):

I propose the synonym:

- Master [grammaticality](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality) ← Synonym [grammaticality-in-context](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality-in-context)

Since [grammatical](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical) only has [one question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/19182/1), I've proposed an edit to retag it as [grammaticality](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality).

English.SE has separate tags for [[grammar]](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/grammar/info) and [[grammaticality]](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/grammaticality/info), so perhaps we should maintain that distinction here too.  (Consistency with English.SE, even if their tag taxonomy is not ideal, would at least facilitate migration of questions between sites.)