# The problem with tags

Tags: discussion, tags

The aim of Stackexchange of trying to deliver good answers to grammar questions is excellent, but nevertheless Stackexchange has still a lot to do. I have just read the post "Why is present perfect used in this sentence?" and given a comment. Then I looked at the posts with the tag "present perfect simple". About 450 posts. Impossible to find a post where an exemplary answer is given to the question "When to use present perfect simple (Pf)?".

I see this as a problem and this may be the cause why the search function for tags is little used. How could one solve this problem? Should posts with exemplary answers have a special colour and be placed at the beginning of the endless row of posts?

Comment: Just sort by votes?

Comment: Yes, that idea also went through my mind.  Perhaps a limited number of  grammar questions, really frequently asked questions,  should be put up for votes "What do you think are the best answers?"

Comment: We do have [tag:canonical-post] for somewhat of a similar purpose. It's presently sparsely populated because the standards are quite high.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's see [why we have tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31776/why-do-we-tag-questions):

- > Tags are for sorting your question into specific, well-defined categories
- > Tags are used in searching.
- > They are used for (weak) statistics.
- > Some people use them to find unanswered questions they could possibly answer.

On ELL *do* have some tagging problems, such as

- There are many broad and many specific tags. Compare [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) with [future-perfect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/future-perfect) with [cleft-constructions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleft-constructions).
- Many tags don't have a decent summary; thus, many mis-tag questions.
- We have many, many similar or redundant tags and we don't have anywhere to point ELLers to regarding which tag to use. Compare [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) with [grammaticality](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality) (see also [this discussion](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/tag-cluster-grammar-grammaticality-grammaticality-in-context-grammati)) or [meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning), [meaning-in-context](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context), [word-meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning), [sentence-meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-meaning) and the like.

## But

This isn't a problem with the tags (!). Some SE sites tend to have "canonical questions" so that: (1) They'll be able to close further related questions as their duplicates. and (2) They'll have a sustainable source of info. (3) Other benefits.

We currently only have two canonical posts on ELL: [Canonical Post #1: When to Trust Your Grammar Checker](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8743/canonical-post-1-when-to-trust-your-grammar-checker?s=2|1.0725) and [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it?s=3|0.7859).

We'll need to write other ones and there are no canonical posts for each of the aspects. For that cause a meta post or chat event can act as a good formal medium to invite people to chip in.

As for how to keep track of the question, you can

- use advanced search tips
- use Google with `site:ell.stackexchange.com` (specially if you remember a portion of a text in comments)
- favorite it

in order to find it.

Comment: At the time, no one else was interested in writing a canonical post, so the initiative sort of dried up... I'd love to start it back up again. Would you be interested in writing one?

Comment: @Wendi I occasionally see Stoney in chat saying that they didn't reach a consensus. Of course I'd love to help, but I don't think I have what it takes to write one. Of course, we could make a team or something, and arrange it. It could be a weird new meta post, or just a friendly campfire in chat.